# How do I remove the line after merged the 2 objects together?

Tags: modeling

[image][image: line after merged 2 objects]
[image][image]

Hi, How do I remove the line after merged the 2 objects together? before I subdivided in multiresolution everything seem ok but after that it look like in the picture.

[image]

Comment: hello, maybe it's a problem of flipped normals? Maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would go into edit mode and look for duplicate vertices and merge them. Then check your edge flow and see if those that are there need adjustment, and maybe add/remove some loops in that area. It looks like it's really pinched in there, which is streatching the existing polygons, which in turn stretches your shading. AS a low poly model it won't do much, but as you subdivide, Blender will make calculations based on the existing geomotry that is there, so that's where I would start. Good luck :)

Comment: i tried to look into it but i didnt see duplicates